# Create a Custom Controller by artisan command laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am developing a package, I need to create a command for it which creates a controller the code looks like this:

```
 class MyCommand extends Command {

   protected $name = 'package:mycommand';

   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
   }

   public function fire()
   {                      
     $this->call('vendor:publish');

     $argName = $this->argument('name'); 

    $this->call('make:controller', ['name' => $argName.'Controller']);

   }
```

This command works and it creates a controller which looks like this:

```
 class wwController extends Controller {


    public function index()
    {

     }
}
```

and also some other functions are there but their are not implemented,

Question:
Is there anyway to create a custom `controller` which extends from one of the controller in my package, let's say `MyController` and also has the functions of `MyController`
or if this is not possible with this command, is there any other command suitable for this purpose?
I need to create a controller with command like this:

```
 class newController extends MyController {

   public function myFunction()
   {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to scaffold a controller you may want to checkout [Laracast/Generator](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) project for an example of how this sort of thing could be done.

In the [MigrationMakeCommand.php](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended/blob/master/src/Commands/MigrationMakeCommand.php) Jeffrey (I assume the author here) creates a command that generates a migration file based on some command line parameters you pass into that command. This is fairly similar to what you're trying to do.

As far as I can tell you'll wan to inject the file system and composer as the author did on **line 56**

```
/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @param Filesystem $files
 * @param Composer $composer
 */
public function __construct(Filesystem $files, Composer $composer)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->files = $files;
    $this->composer = $composer;
}
```

Then you'll want to pay particularly close attention to the chain method calls on **line 156** that's pretty close to the steps you'll need to take to make a new controller file.

```
protected function compileMigrationStub()
{
    $stub = $this->files->get(__DIR__ . '/../stubs/migration.stub');
    $this->replaceClassName($stub)
        ->replaceSchema($stub)
        ->replaceTableName($stub);
    return $stub;
}
```